# Show that a non-constant holomorphic function has zeroes in a compact set

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struggling with the following exercise:

> Let $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a domain and let $K \subset G$ be compact with non-empty interior. Let further be $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic and non-constant function with $\lvert f(z) \rvert = C$ for all $z \in \partial K$ and some constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Show that $f$ must have zeroes in $K$.

My idea is this: I think it should be true that the the maximum value of $f$ on $K$ has to be on the boundary of $f(K)$ and is due to our assumption equal to $C$. So the disk centered at $0$ with radius $C$ should contain $K$. All the values of $f$ in the interior of this disk have to be smaller than $C$ , however. I guess that we may now conclude that $f$ has to be equal to $0$ for some point in $K$.

Could you tell me if I am on the right track?

Comment: Assuming $f$ has no zero, think about $1/f$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I can only see the following: If $f$ has no zeroes on $K$ then we can safely define $1/f$. On the boundary of $K$ $1/f$ takes on $1/C$ and insided $K$ the values of $f$ have to be smaller. But I do not see what comes now.

Comment: You know $|1/f|\le1/C$, so $|f|\ge C$. You also know $|f|\le C$, and hence $|f|=C$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I fear I still do not get it. You are saying that $\lvert f \rvert \equiv C$ on $K$. I can follow you that far. If I understand you right you now want to argue that $f \equiv C$ on $G$. I guess that you want to use the Identity Theorem with the following argument: $K$ is compact, thus it has an accumulation point and since $f \equiv C$ on $K$ we have $f \equiv C$ on $G$ by the  Identity Theorem. But I have an objections to this: $f= \lvert C \rvert $ does not imply $f = C$. Do I misunderstand anything?

Comment: Yes, you're misunderstanding a great deal. The fact that $|f|=C$ shows that $f$ is constant; of course it does not imply $f=C$. You should probably have learned the Open Mapping Theorem by now...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I think I got it now: We can use the Identity Theorem to see that $\lvert f \rvert \equiv C$ on $G$ as outlined above. And since $G$ is a domain and $f$ is holomorphic the fact that $\lvert f \rvert $ is constant implies that $f$ is also constant. I am rather sure that this should work. I would still be interested how you can use the Open Mapping Theorem here; could you explain?

Comment: The question is how $|f|$ constant implies $f$ constant. Can you _state_ the OMT? Is $\{z:|z|=C\}$ an open set?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I got it now, you use the OMT and the fact that $\{z \mid \lvert z \rvert = C \}$ is not open to prove that $\lvert f \rvert \text{ constant } \implies f  \text{ constant }$. Till now I have only seen this proved via the Cauchy-Riemann Differential Equations; hence my confusion. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can also get it from the C-R equations, yes. Using OMT seems simpler/cleaner; as we saw in the first version of the answer, getting it from the C-R equations involves $\log f$, which then leads to an argument that has to be stated carefully, since $\log f$ exists locally but not globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By maximum modulus principle, $|f|\le C$ on $K$.

Assume there are no zeroes in $K$, then by minimum modulus principle $|f|\ge C$ on $K$. Therefore, $|f|\equiv C$ on $K$.

Choose an arbitrary $z_0\in K$. By assumption $f(z_0)$ is non-zero, thus $g:=\operatorname{log} f$ defines a holomorphic function on a open neighbourhood $B$ of $z_0$ (composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic).

We notice $\Re g=\operatorname{log}|f|=\ln C$ is constant on $B$, thus by Cauchy-Riemann’s equations $\Im g$ is also constant on $B$. Hence, $g$ is constant on $B$, and so is $f$. By identity theorem, $f$ is constant on $K$, contradicting the given condition that $f$ is non-constant.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for pointing out such serious mistake. I guess $f(z)=z$ defined on an origin-certered annulus is an example of your claim. I have modified the proof accordingly. Regarding your second point, I did not assume $|f|=C$ on $K$. I derived it under the assumption of absence of zeroes.